# How to edit two pages in word from different page number side by side?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

How to edit two pages in word from different page number side by side?

Say I am copying selective data from page number 1 to page number 100 . Instead of scrolling back and forth can I see them side by side.

---

***Using Office 2002 .Could not find tag for 2002 office.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a split view in Word - look in the View menu or Ribbon, click Split. Then you basically have an upper and lower view of the document that are independent in terms of where they begin.